# Firebase setDisplayName has no effect

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase's custom authentication.

I'm trying to set a user's username with:

```
UserProfileChangeRequest userProfileChangeRequest = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                .setDisplayName("Hello")
                .build();
        assert currentUser != null;

        currentUser.updateProfile(userProfileChangeRequest).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(UsernameAndProfilePictureChooserActivity.this, "Success. Username: " + getUsername(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else {
                    throw new Error(task.getException().getMessage(),task.getException().getCause());
                }
            }
        });
```

But it has no effect.

The Toast message (`Toast.makeText(UsernameAndProfilePictureChooserActivity.this, "Success. Username: " + getUsername(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` gets called, but getUsername(), which is `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName()` returns null.

Closing the app then re-opening it doesn't work.

Why is this happening?

Comment: There is a bug in Firebase, Close the app and again re-open it. It works fine

Comment: @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy nope. It didn't work for me.

Comment: Just tried your code and it works for me. I am using `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0`. I would say check your `currentUser` object and your `getUsername()` method.

Comment: @Distwo maybe because I need to update my firebase version... Will do

Comment: @AbAppletic did that work?

Comment: @Distwo yes, please post it as an answer and you will be awarded the bounty

Comment: Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update the version of your firebase auth library.

I am using `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0` and it works for me.